# onSharedPreferenceChanged edit stored value?

Tags: android, preferences, sharedpreferences

If I have a onSharedPreferenceChanged event in my PreferenceActivity, that is checking if a CheckBoxPreference is checked or not and setting setEnabled on some other Preference, does the actual value of the other Preference get changed in the SharedPreferences, or do I have to manually set them?

What I have is:

```
 public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(Settings sharedPreferences, String key) 
 {
      CheckBoxPreference cbUpdatesEnabled = (CheckBoxPreference)getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("updatesenabled");

      CheckBoxPreference cbVibrate = (CheckBoxPreference)getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("vibrate");

      cbVibrate.setEnabled(cbUpdatesEnabled.isChecked());
 }
```

Which toggles whether the "vibrate" checkbox is enabled or disabled in the UI, but then do I also have to use:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("vibrate", cbUpdatesEnabled.isChecked());
editor.commit();
```

Or is there some other way of updating the SharedPreferences?  It doesn't look like the value is automatically saved just based on if it's enabled or not.

Comment: Yes you have to manually set shared preference value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to manually update the preference value if you are using PreferenceActivity.
For more information check following tutorials.

[Click here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120626000119/http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences)

[Click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html)